# javascript get another domain's source

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-get-contents

Is there any way to get full page source of snother different site? Example my site is example.com but i want to get facebook's page source on example.com. I tired this one: http://phpjs.org/functions/file_get_contents/ 
And it gives me null. So anyone knows it?

```
function file_get_contents (url, flags, context, offset, maxLen) {
  // Read the entire file into a string
  //
  // version: 906.111
  // discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/file_get_contents
  // +   original by: Legaev Andrey
  // +      input by: Jani Hartikainen
  // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // +   improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // +   input by: Raphael (Ao) RUDLER
  // +   bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  // %        note 1: This function uses XmlHttpRequest and cannot retrieve resource from different domain without modifications.
  // %        note 2: Synchronous by default (as in PHP) so may lock up browser. Can
  // %        note 2: get async by setting a custom "phpjs.async" property to true and "notification" for an
  // %        note 2: optional callback (both as context params, with responseText, and other JS-specific
  // %        note 2: request properties available via 'this'). Note that file_get_contents() will not return the text
  // %        note 2: in such a case (use this.responseText within the callback). Or, consider using
  // %        note 2: jQuery's: $('#divId').load('http://url') instead.
  // %        note 3: The context argument is only implemented for http, and only partially (see below for
  // %        note 3: "Presently unimplemented HTTP context options"); also the arguments passed to
  // %        note 3: notification are incomplete
  // *     example 1: file_get_contents('http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/pj_test_supportfile_1.htm');
  // *     returns 1: '123'
  // Note: could also be made to optionally add to global $http_response_header as per http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php
  var tmp, headers = [],
    newTmp = [],
    k = 0,
    i = 0,
    href = '',
    pathPos = -1,
    flagNames = 0,
    content = null,
    http_stream = false;
  var func = function (value) {
    return value.substring(1) !== '';
  };

  // BEGIN REDUNDANT
  this.php_js = this.php_js || {};
  this.php_js.ini = this.php_js.ini || {};
  // END REDUNDANT
  var ini = this.php_js.ini;
  context = context || this.php_js.default_streams_context || null;

  if (!flags) {
    flags = 0;
  }
  var OPTS = {
    FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH: 1,
    FILE_TEXT: 32,
    FILE_BINARY: 64
  };
  if (typeof flags === 'number') { // Allow for a single string or an array of string flags
    flagNames = flags;
  } else {
    flags = [].concat(flags);
    for (i = 0; i < flags.length; i++) {
      if (OPTS[flags[i]]) {
        flagNames = flagNames | OPTS[flags[i]];
      }
    }
  }

  if (flagNames & OPTS.FILE_BINARY && (flagNames & OPTS.FILE_TEXT)) { // These flags shouldn't be together
    throw 'You cannot pass both FILE_BINARY and FILE_TEXT to file_get_contents()';
  }

  if ((flagNames & OPTS.FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH) && ini.include_path && ini.include_path.local_value) {
    var slash = ini.include_path.local_value.indexOf('/') !== -1 ? '/' : '\\';
    url = ini.include_path.local_value + slash + url;
  } else if (!/^(https?|file):/.test(url)) { // Allow references within or below the same directory (should fix to allow other relative references or root reference; could make dependent on parse_url())
    href = this.window.location.href;
    pathPos = url.indexOf('/') === 0 ? href.indexOf('/', 8) - 1 : href.lastIndexOf('/');
    url = href.slice(0, pathPos + 1) + url;
  }

  if (context) {
    var http_options = context.stream_options && context.stream_options.http;
    http_stream = !! http_options;
  }

  if (!context || http_stream) {
    var req = this.window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (!req) {
      throw new Error('XMLHttpRequest not supported');
    }

    var method = http_stream ? http_options.method : 'GET';
    var async = !! (context && context.stream_params && context.stream_params['phpjs.async']);

    if (ini['phpjs.ajaxBypassCache'] && ini['phpjs.ajaxBypassCache'].local_value) {
      url += (url.match(/\?/) == null ? "?" : "&") + (new Date()).getTime(); // Give optional means of forcing bypass of cache
    }

    req.open(method, url, async);
    if (async) {
      var notification = context.stream_params.notification;
      if (typeof notification === 'function') {
        // Fix: make work with req.addEventListener if available: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest
        if (0 && req.addEventListener) { // Unimplemented so don't allow to get here
/*
          req.addEventListener('progress', updateProgress, false);
          req.addEventListener('load', transferComplete, false);
          req.addEventListener('error', transferFailed, false);
          req.addEventListener('abort', transferCanceled, false);
          */
        } else {
          req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) { // aEvt has stopPropagation(), preventDefault(); see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NsIDOMEvent
            // Other XMLHttpRequest properties: multipart, responseXML, status, statusText, upload, withCredentials
/*
  PHP Constants:
  STREAM_NOTIFY_RESOLVE   1       A remote address required for this stream has been resolved, or the resolution failed. See severity  for an indication of which happened.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_CONNECT   2     A connection with an external resource has been established.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_AUTH_REQUIRED 3     Additional authorization is required to access the specified resource. Typical issued with severity level of STREAM_NOTIFY_SEVERITY_ERR.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_MIME_TYPE_IS  4     The mime-type of resource has been identified, refer to message for a description of the discovered type.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_FILE_SIZE_IS  5     The size of the resource has been discovered.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_REDIRECTED    6     The external resource has redirected the stream to an alternate location. Refer to message .
  STREAM_NOTIFY_PROGRESS  7     Indicates current progress of the stream transfer in bytes_transferred and possibly bytes_max as well.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_COMPLETED 8     There is no more data available on the stream.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_FAILURE   9     A generic error occurred on the stream, consult message and message_code for details.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_AUTH_RESULT   10     Authorization has been completed (with or without success).

  STREAM_NOTIFY_SEVERITY_INFO 0     Normal, non-error related, notification.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_SEVERITY_WARN 1     Non critical error condition. Processing may continue.
  STREAM_NOTIFY_SEVERITY_ERR  2     A critical error occurred. Processing cannot continue.
  */
            var objContext = {
              responseText: req.responseText,
              responseXML: req.responseXML,
              status: req.status,
              statusText: req.statusText,
              readyState: req.readyState,
              evt: aEvt
            }; // properties are not available in PHP, but offered on notification via 'this' for convenience
            // notification args: notification_code, severity, message, message_code, bytes_transferred, bytes_max (all int's except string 'message')
            // Need to add message, etc.
            var bytes_transferred;
            switch (req.readyState) {
            case 0:
              //     UNINITIALIZED     open() has not been called yet.
              notification.call(objContext, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0);
              break;
            case 1:
              //     LOADING     send() has not been called yet.
              notification.call(objContext, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0);
              break;
            case 2:
              //     LOADED     send() has been called, and headers and status are available.
              notification.call(objContext, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0);
              break;
            case 3:
              //     INTERACTIVE     Downloading; responseText holds partial data.
              bytes_transferred = req.responseText.length * 2; // One character is two bytes
              notification.call(objContext, 7, 0, '', 0, bytes_transferred, 0);
              break;
            case 4:
              //     COMPLETED     The operation is complete.
              if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
                bytes_transferred = req.responseText.length * 2; // One character is two bytes
                notification.call(objContext, 8, 0, '', req.status, bytes_transferred, 0);
              } else if (req.status === 403) { // Fix: These two are finished except for message
                notification.call(objContext, 10, 2, '', req.status, 0, 0);
              } else { // Errors
                notification.call(objContext, 9, 2, '', req.status, 0, 0);
              }
              break;
            default:
              throw 'Unrecognized ready state for file_get_contents()';
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    if (http_stream) {
      var sendHeaders = http_options.header && http_options.header.split(/\r?\n/);
      var userAgentSent = false;
      for (i = 0; i < sendHeaders.length; i++) {
        var sendHeader = sendHeaders[i];
        var breakPos = sendHeader.search(/:\s*/);
        var sendHeaderName = sendHeader.substring(0, breakPos);
        req.setRequestHeader(sendHeaderName, sendHeader.substring(breakPos + 1));
        if (sendHeaderName === 'User-Agent') {
          userAgentSent = true;
        }
      }
      if (!userAgentSent) {
        var user_agent = http_options.user_agent || (ini.user_agent && ini.user_agent.local_value);
        if (user_agent) {
          req.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', user_agent);
        }
      }
      content = http_options.content || null;
/*
      // Presently unimplemented HTTP context options
      var request_fulluri = http_options.request_fulluri || false; // When set to TRUE, the entire URI will be used when constructing the request. (i.e. GET http://www.example.com/path/to/file.html HTTP/1.0). While this is a non-standard request format, some proxy servers require it.
      var max_redirects = http_options.max_redirects || 20; // The max number of redirects to follow. Value 1 or less means that no redirects are followed.
      var protocol_version = http_options.protocol_version || 1.0; // HTTP protocol version
      var timeout = http_options.timeout || (ini.default_socket_timeout && ini.default_socket_timeout.local_value); // Read timeout in seconds, specified by a float
      var ignore_errors = http_options.ignore_errors || false; // Fetch the content even on failure status codes.
      */
    }

    if (flagNames & OPTS.FILE_TEXT) { // Overrides how encoding is treated (regardless of what is returned from the server)
      var content_type = 'text/html';
      if (http_options && http_options['phpjs.override']) { // Fix: Could allow for non-HTTP as well
        content_type = http_options['phpjs.override']; // We use this, e.g., in gettext-related functions if character set
        //   overridden earlier by bind_textdomain_codeset()
      } else {
        var encoding = (ini['unicode.stream_encoding'] && ini['unicode.stream_encoding'].local_value) || 'UTF-8';
        if (http_options && http_options.header && (/^content-type:/im).test(http_options.header)) { // We'll assume a content-type expects its own specified encoding if present
          content_type = http_options.header.match(/^content-type:\s*(.*)$/im)[1]; // We let any header encoding stand
        }
        if (!(/;\s*charset=/).test(content_type)) { // If no encoding
          content_type += '; charset=' + encoding;
        }
      }
      req.overrideMimeType(content_type);
    }
    // Default is FILE_BINARY, but for binary, we apparently deviate from PHP in requiring the flag, since many if not
    //     most people will also want a way to have it be auto-converted into native JavaScript text instead
    else if (flagNames & OPTS.FILE_BINARY) { // Trick at https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest to get binary
      req.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
      // Getting an individual byte then requires:
      // responseText.charCodeAt(x) & 0xFF; // throw away high-order byte (f7) where x is 0 to responseText.length-1 (see notes in our substr())
    }

    try {
      if (http_options && http_options['phpjs.sendAsBinary']) { // For content sent in a POST or PUT request (use with file_put_contents()?)
        req.sendAsBinary(content); // In Firefox, only available FF3+
      } else {
        req.send(content);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      // catches exception reported in issue #66
      return false;
    }

    tmp = req.getAllResponseHeaders();
    if (tmp) {
      tmp = tmp.split('\n');
      for (k = 0; k < tmp.length; k++) {
        if (func(tmp[k])) {
          newTmp.push(tmp[k]);
        }
      }
      tmp = newTmp;
      for (i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
        headers[i] = tmp[i];
      }
      this.$http_response_header = headers; // see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php
    }

    if (offset || maxLen) {
      if (maxLen) {
        return req.responseText.substr(offset || 0, maxLen);
      }
      return req.responseText.substr(offset);
    }
    return req.responseText;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: To quote the source code you pasted: *note 1: This function uses XmlHttpRequest and cannot retrieve resource from different domain without modifications.*

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible via javascript. Any request made via javascript must made be to the same domain as the originator. This is a security feature of most browsers known as the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

The only work-around is to scrape the source of the external domain via a server-side language, such as `PHP` or `ASP.Net` and then make the AJAX request to that locally.

Comment: Note that you could also have an external service do the scraping, such as YQL, though it's the same concept (YQL would of course return it as json rather than plain html).